# When are variables evaluated in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
$startdate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("-1 week"));

$query = "SELECT title FROM new_books ".
         "WHERE timestamp >= '$startdate' ";
$newbooks = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Is the value of `$startdate` evaluated when $query is set, or when it's called by `mysql_query()`?

For example say the above query returns 0 results (`mysql_num_rows($newbook)==0`) could I change `$startdate` and then call `$newbooks = mysql_query...` again, or would I need to set `$query` again first?

Comment: It's not a mysql query, it's a PHP string that gets PASSED to mysql_query() and gets treated as a query. The variable is interpolated into the string BEFORE mysql_query gets called, at the moment the string is assigned to `$query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is evaluated at the time $query is set.

It's exactly like doing this:

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM new_books ".
         "WHERE timestamp >= '" . $startdate . "' ";
```

If you want to execute the same query multiple times with different parameters, use **[prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title FROM new_books WHERE timestamp >= :startdate");

$query->bind_params("s", $startdate);
$query->execute();
...

$query->bind_params("s", $an_other_startdate);
$query->execute();
...
```

See the examples at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to use the following?

`$query->bind_param('s', $startdate);
$startdate = $date1;
$query->execute();
...
$startdate = $date2;
$query->execute();
...`

Answer (score 1):

Because it's encapsulated in double quotes, it will be evaluated when setting $query.

Comment: Is there a way to form the `$query` so that it's not evaluated until it's sent to `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a query like that, you are doing nothing but string concatenation as @arnaud576875 mentioned. You if you change the $startdate variable, you would need to reset the query.

You could potentially use sprintf like this before you pass it to mysql_query

```
$query_format = "SELECT title FROM new_books WHERE timestamp >= '%s'";
$newbooks = mysql_query(sprintf($query_format, $startdate)) or die (mysql_error());
```

Or just use prepared statements as suggested